# Writing re-entrant lexer with Flex

Tags: thread-safety, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis, reentrancy

I'm newbie to flex. I'm trying to write a simple re-entrant lexer/scanner with flex. The lexer definition goes below. I get stuck with compilation errors as shown below (yyg issue):

### reentrant.l:

```
/* Definitions */

digit           [0-9]
letter          [a-zA-Z]
alphanum        [a-zA-Z0-9]
identifier      [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]+
integer         [0-9]+
natural         [0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*
decimal         ([0-9]+\.|\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)

%{
    #include <stdio.h>

    #define ECHO fwrite(yytext, yyleng, 1, yyout)

    int totalNums = 0;
%}

%option reentrant
%option prefix="simpleit_"

%%

^(.*)\r?\n     printf("%d\t%s", yylineno++, yytext);

%%
/* Routines */

int yywrap(yyscan_t yyscanner)
{
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    yyscan_t yyscanner;

    if(argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s fileName\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "rb");

    yylex(yyscanner);

    return 0;
}
```

### Compilation errors:

```
vietlq@mylappie:~/Desktop/parsers/reentrant$ gcc lex.simpleit_.c 
reentrant.l: In function ‘main’:
reentrant.l:44: error: ‘yyg’ undeclared (first use in this function)
reentrant.l:44: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
reentrant.l:44: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For a reentrant lexer, all communication must include the *state*, which is contained within the *scanner*.

Anywhere in your program (*e.g.* inside `main`) you can access the state variables via special functions to which you will pass your scanner. *E.g.*, in your original `reentrant.l`, you can do this:

```
yyscan_t scanner;
yylex_init(&scanner);
yyset_in(fopen(argv[1], "rb"), scanner);
yylex(scanner);
yylex_destroy(scanner);
```

I have renamed `scanner` to avoid confusion with `yyscanner` in the actions. In contrast with general C code, all your actions occur within a giant function called `yylex`, which is passed your scanner by the name `yyscanner`. Thus, `yyscanner` is available to all your actions. In addition, `yylex` has a local variable called `yyg` that holds the entire state, and most macros conveniently refer to `yyg`.

While it is true that you can use the `yyin` macro inside `main` by defining `yyg` as you did in your own Answer, that is not recommended. For a reentrant lexer, the macros are meant for actions only.

To see how this is implemented, you can always view the generated code:

```
/* For convenience, these vars
   are macros in the reentrant scanner. */
#define yyin yyg->yyin_r
...

/* Holds the entire state of the reentrant scanner. */
struct yyguts_t
...

#define YY_DECL int yylex (yyscan_t yyscanner)

/** The main scanner function which does all the work.
 */
YY_DECL
{
    struct yyguts_t * yyg = (struct yyguts_t*)yyscanner;
...
}
```

There is lots more on the `reentrant` option in the **flex** docs, which include a cleanly compiling example. (Google "*flex reentrant*", and look for the `flex.sourceforge` link.) Unlike **bison**, **flex** has a fairly straight-forward model for reentrancy. I strongly suggest using reentrant **flex** with [**Lemon** Parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemon_Parser), rather than with **yacc/bison**.

Comment: Anything besides the above initialization that is needed?  I get a crash in the internals, it appears that yy_cp is a null pointer after assignment to yyg->yy_c_buf_p.

Comment: It's hard to debug through comments. What I posted worked for me inside `main()` in *reentrant.l* from the OP.

Comment: I know this is really old - however I have been attempting to use lex. I have found that if I use BEGIN or any of the start condition macros, they still get the yyg undeclared message. I was, like you, able to get this simplistic main() only lexer working. I will attempt to define yyg in my function to see if that fixes it for my other functions that attempt to change stat conditions.